# Is there Cloud Page reporting in SFMC?

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage, sfmc-business-unit, google-analytics, sfmcadmin

0
we have built a Cloud Page as a registration Form and would like to get some reporting on it.  Does Google Analytics provide anything( we do not have GA360 but just the free account in MC but we have GA4 )

So we have connected SFMC GA to the GA 4 acount but no metrics are showing up on GA4 and this is the first time i am doing it so i am not sure what are the things to setup and ad.

Answer (score 0):

You should treat your Cloud Pages as any other HTML page, where you can place your GA tags into the source code. Either directly or by using Google Tag Manager. There is nothing in the GA-SDMC integration, which would provide page visits etc. into your GA account, as it will not place the tracking tags automatically into Cloud Pages.

Comment: How do we get the google tags? what is the code? any reference

Comment: Standard GA tags… @Reva